# Trouble in using MVVM binding

Tags: wpf, wcf, xaml, mvvm

I tried to apply MVVM in a client which used WCF to get data.
In the first place,it worked fine with MVVM binding. but I has been getting stuck in a trouble.
In my program, there is a "MainWindows" which inherit  from window serves as a base UI, and  contains a user control named "HomeControl". when i added the line 
"this.DataContext = new HomeViewModel();" in the HomeContorl.xaml.cs. The HomeControl did not show in the mainwindows and told me that

```
"
In the ServiceModel client configuration section, can not find a reference to the Agreement "ITestWcf" default endpoint element. This may be because the application configuration file is not found , or because the client can not find endpoint element with this agreement matched elements .
   In System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadChannelBehaviors (ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, String configurationName)
   In System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration (String configurationName, Configuration configuration)
   In System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration (String configurationName)
   In System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint (String configurationName, EndpointAddress address)
   In System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory `1 .. ctor (String endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
   In System.ServiceModel.ConfigurationEndpointTrait `1.CreateSimplexFactory ()
   In System.ServiceModel.ConfigurationEndpointTrait `1.CreateChannelFactory ()
   In System.ServiceModel.ClientBase `1.CreateChannelFactoryRef (EndpointTrait` 1 endpointTrait)
   In System.ServiceModel.ClientBase `1.InitializeChannelFactoryRef ()
   In System.ServiceModel.ClientBase `1 .. ctor ()
   In TestWcfClient .. ctor () Location D: \ Cswork \ Visual Studio 2010 \ Projects \ InterfaceCom - bk20131113 - copy \ Client0.1 \ Client0.1 \ testproxy.cs: line number 995
   In TestViewModel.BaseViewModel .. ctor () Location D: \ Cswork \ Visual Studio 2010 \ Projects \ InterfaceCom - bk20131113 - copy \ Client0.1 \ Client0.1 \ BaseViewModel.cs: line 18
   In TestViewModel.LoginViewModel .. ctor () Location D: \ Cswork \ Visual Studio 2010 \ Projects \ InterfaceCom - bk20131113 - copy \ Client0.1 \ Client0.1 \ LoginViewModel.cs: line 38
   In Client0_1.HomeControl .. ctor () Location D: \ Cswork \ Visual Studio 2010 \ Projects \ InterfaceCom - bk20131113 - copy \ Client0.1 \ Client0.1 \ HomeControl.xaml.cs: line 28
"
```

I changed related content in the app.config, but the problem stay still .Only if i delete the line "this.DataContext = new HomeViewModel()" i mentioned before, the problem  gone . what is the reason and how to make it works ? thanks very much.

Comment: You get this error in the designer? It doesn't affect the ability for it to build/run?

Comment: yes.In designer mode,it's fail to build.it get me the reason

Comment: Are you sure that your WCF settings are valid? Have you tried to get data from service? It looks like a trouble with applying of app config settings

Comment: Please try to create an instance of View Model and to read in try catch block it's properties to be sure that it possible to read data

Comment: Thanks, In designer mode,it's fail to build and throw the reason "Error 28 can not create an instance of 'HomeControl'". I trace this reason,back to mainwindow. I found out the place i had put  "homeContorl" showing a blank with red Crosses instead of the UserContorl, And gave the clue I have posted. By the way i did not put codes to use WCF proxy in the viewmodel behind Homecontorl

Comment: potehin143, thanks for you advisement. I will try

Comment: It looks like your constructor in BaseViewModel is calling your service? Are you sure you have endpoints properly configured in your app.config file?

Comment: Thanks.Lee O, in others parts of client,there is no problem to call webservice and use the MVVM. only in this usercontrol .Is this reason that Usercontrol designed fail to use MVVM? I use some Viewmodels which  work fine in binding with other windows derived View,but  hardly to binding with this Usercontrol